# How to check run time of your code in Python. PyCharm is my IDE

Tags: python, runtime, pycharm

How do I check how long it takes for my code to execute. Is there an inbuilt way in python. Or is there some hidden tool in my IDE PyCharm that let's me do so.

Comment: in additions to the answers of the original question, you can check the `timeit` module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try with

```
cProfile
```

in this way:

```
import cProfile
def myFunc():
   ...

cProfile.run('myFunc()')
```

Hope this solves your question!

Answer (score 0):

So profiler is already builtin tool in Pycharm, it uses `cProfiler` by default if you don't have `yappi` installed. Here is the link to it [PyCharm profiler](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/profiler.html).

And if you want profile your code without any attachment to PyCharm, check that SO question [How can you profile a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script)